# Lubuntu/Openbox does not recognize bash variable in lubuntu-rc.xml command

Tags: command-line, bash, lubuntu, shortcut-keys, openbox

Here is an action I have added to lubuntu-rc.xml

```
<!-- Reference files menu -->  
<keybind key="W-l">  
<action name="Execute">  
<command>eval "xterm -e links $HD/Reference/index.html"</command>  
</action>  
</keybind>
```

Pressing Window+l fails, producing the message

> Failed to execute child process eval. No such file or directory.

Running the eval in an xterm works as it should. The problem is with $HD, which I make available in my .bashrc with

```
export HD=/media/q/a5fe16da-59d0-48ae-b985-aa42119e1db5
```

If I substitute the actual path from above line for $HD in the  above, then pressing Window+l produces the desired result.

How do I get Lubuntu/Openbox to recognize the content of $HD?

Comment: Did you try `<command>xterm -e "bash -c links $HD/Reference/index.html"</command>`? You may need to start `bash` as an interactive shell explicitly, add the `-i` flag to do that or read your `.bashrc` explicitly with `--rcfile /path/to/.bashrc`.

Comment: The 3 possibilities all do the same thing, links starts but shows no content, though its taskbar icon shows the file it should be showing. Thanks, but I'll just use the explicit filepath instead.

Comment: If things still don't work make an executable script to use the command and then just point to the script in your lubuntu-rc.xml.

Comment: I was looking for a way to launch gvim from a keybind and still have access to my environment (e.g. my PATH as defined in .bashrc). @dessert's comment was what finally provided me with the answer I needed. Specifically I now have this as my execute command: `bash -ic "gvim"`. The `-i` is what made the difference.